# SQL sub query for sum

Tags: mysql, metabase

Need to sum up duration for students with the same name

```
select (select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) from users where review_histories.review_user_id=users.id) as Reviewer,
review_histories.review_end as ReviewDate, exam_id as ExamID, user_name as StudentName,
videos.duration as Duration,
#Select avg(videos.duration)/60 from videos where students.exam_id=exams.id and file_type in (10,11) as AvgDuration
student_file_types.code as 'Video Type'

from review_histories

left join users on review_histories.review_user_id=users.id
left join students on review_histories.student_id=students.id
left join exams on students.exam_id=exams.id
left join student_files on student_files.student_id = students.id
left join student_file_types on student_file_types.id=student_files.file_type
left join videos on videos.id = student_files.video_id

where {{enddate}} and users.first_name LIKE CONCAT('%',{{name}},'%') or {{enddate}} and users.last_name LIKE CONCAT('%',{{name}},'%') or {{enddate}} and RTRIM(LTRIM(CONCAT(COALESCE(users.first_name),COALESCE(" "),COALESCE(users.last_name)))) LIKE CONCAT('%',{{name}},'%') and users.id = review_histories.review_user_id and review_histories.review_flag <> false and student_file_types.code = 'webrtc_video'

order by ReviewDate asc
```

[Current results]

| Reviewer | Review date | exam_ID | StudentName | Duration | Video Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael E | May 11, 2021, 10:15 AM | 1 | Jeff A | 700 | webrtc_video |
| Michael E | May 11, 2021, 10:15 AM | 1 | Jeff A | 700 | webrtc_video |
| Michael E | May 11, 2021, 11:15 AM | 1 | Bob B | 600 | webrtc_video |
| Michael E | May 11, 2021, 11:15 AM | 1 | Bob B | 600 | webrtc_video |
| Michael E | May 11, 2021, 12:15 PM | 2 | Alex C | 1,600 | webrtc_video |

[Desired result]

| Reviewer | Review date | exam_ID | StudentName | Duration | Video Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael E | May 11, 2021, 10:15 AM | 1 | Jeff A | 1,400 | webrtc_video |
| Michael E | May 11, 2021, 11:15 AM | 1 | Bob B | 1,200 | webrtc_video |
| Michael E | May 11, 2021, 12:15 PM | 2 | Alex C | 1,600 | webrtc_video |

Comment: Use `SUM(duration)` and `GROUP BY Reviewer`, isn't that obvious?

Comment: Thanks.. Group by StudentName. I do appreciate the help.